# Phonegap,ios filereader doesn't work

Tags: ios, html, cordova, filereader

```
var xml2;

function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem){
    fileSystem.root.getFile("ccw.xml", null, gotFile, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
}

function gotFile(file) {
    readAsText(file);
}

function readAsText(file) {

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsText(file);    

    reader.onload = function(){
    };

    xml2 = reader.result;

    writeJson();

}

function fail(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}

function parseXml(xml) {

    var dom = null;

    if (window.DOMParser) {
        try {
            dom = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
        }
        catch (e) { dom = null; }
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            dom = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');

            dom.async = false;

            if (!dom.loadXML(xml)) // parse error ..
          window.alert(dom.parseError.reason + dom.parseError.srcText);
        }
        catch (e) { dom = null; }
    }
    else
       alert("oops");

   return dom;
}

function writeJson(){

    var json;

    //    for(var i = 0 ; i < xml.length ; i++) {
    show("\n\n" + (json = xml2json(parseXml(xml2), "  ")) + "\n\n");
    //        console.log("====="+i+"/"+xml.lenght+"=====");
    //    }
}

function show(s) { 

    document.getElementById("out").innerHTML += (s+"\n").replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace (/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;").replace(/\n/g, "<br/>") + "<hr/>";
}
```

this code is xml to json parsing code. i following the phonegap reference. but my filereader doesn't change stateReady. that is always state 0. please help me..
filereader.result method doesn't work in phonegap?
i want to go home. :-( .i will always see this post.

Comment: is OnDeviceReady invoked by the app? you can test it by putting a simple alert in the OnDeviceReady event.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you probably already solve it, but in case useful for others, your callbacks are not correctly chained, just change your line with this line

```
fileSystem.root.getFile("ccw.xml", null, gotFile, fail);
```

With

```
fileSystem.root.getFile("ccw.xml", null, gotFileEntry, fail`);
```

Try that and also is helpful to add console log messages so its easier for you to debug and understand what happens and in what order.